# android constraintLayout, how to horizontal flow a few views and one of them may show ellipse

Tags: android-constraintlayout, ellipse

Having  A, B, C, D views horizontally flowing one after the other.
If the parent width is wide enough all of them will be displayed

---

### | A | B | C | D

when the parent width is not enough for all, the 3rd one will show ellipse

---

### | AAA | BB | C... | DDD

tried following it works in portrait mode but not in landscape since the `android:maxWidth="100dp"` is used

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a"
        tools:text="CCCCCCCCCCCC long long long long long" />
```

and dont want to make another layout for landscape specifically.

any suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/the_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="83dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/top_row_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/the_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_row_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="top title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/the_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_column_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/the_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_row_title"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/left_icon" />

    <!-- horizontal flow views-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/the_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_row_title"
        tools:text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/a"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/right_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a"
        tools:text="CCCCCCCCCCCC long long long long long" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did't get the point what you're trying to do but, if I'm right then you want to make a **`Horizontal Chain`** in `ConstraintLayout`.

> Find full documentation here : [Control linear groups with a chain](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain)

Comment: dont see how the "chain" would help. The ABCD are started left aligned, and right one attaches the left one (no space distribution if the parent width are larger).